# Reinitializing an array in C++ with braces

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, list-initialization

I'm in a situation where creating new variables constantly isn't really a good option, as I'd like to avoid creating a new array for every instance of an object. Essentially, I have a 'point' class, and a 'polygon' class whose constructor takes a vector of points. Since each point has to be manually and individually set, since there aren't really mathematical progressions between them, the most line-conservative solution I've come up with is something using a 'MakeVector' function I've found around, to convert straight arrays to vectors.

Namely, to create one polygon, I've got this:

```
point ps[]={point(-1,-1,-1),point(1,-1,-1),point(1,1,-1),point(-1,1,-1)};
polygon p1(MakeVector(ps));
```

Even though this particular set of coordinates has a mathematical progression, not all do, as I'm doing some 3D modeling. The following lines are ineffective and throw errors:

```
ps=new point[]{point(-1,-1,1),point(1,-1,1),point(1,1,1),point(-1,1,1)};
```

and

```
ps={point(-1,-1,1),point(1,-1,1),point(1,1,1),point(-1,1,1)};
```

I've tried a few different things, and I come across no real way to do this quickly. I'd rather not have to put a new line for every value in an array I make. What would be the best way to do this, with hard-coded values?

Comment: With `ps` being a `std::vector<point>`, the last works in C++11. So does `ps = {{-1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}};`

Comment: Hm, I appear to be getting an error about this not being available in C++98. How would one update this? I should be using a fairly modern compiler, as I installed this one just last year.

Comment: to assign a new value to a vector, use assignment. to update a single item of a vector, use assignment (to that item. e.g. selected by `[]` or `at`). in short, use **assignment** to assign.

Comment: Worked it out. Turns out, changing `ps` from `point[]` to `vector<point>` was part of the solution, along with finding the _Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]_ flag under Project -> Build Options in Codeblocks.